# add SPListItem with more than one field of data

Tags: list, splistitem, splist, task-list

I want to add an item to a SharePoint task list, with data in the Title, AssignedTo, and Status columns. The code below adds the item with data in the Title column, but no data in the other columns. What do I need to change for this to work?

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://mysharepointserver"));
string strSite = "http://mysharepointserver/sites/testsite/default.aspx";
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(strSite))
{
    using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb("testsite/mysubsite"))
    {
        SPList taskList = web.Lists["Tasks"];
        SPListItem newTask = taskList.Items.Add();
        newTask["Title"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        newTask["AssignedTo"] = @"mydomain\jdoe";
        newTask["Status"] = "In Progress";
        newTask.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe because you didn't write any metadata in the other columns?

Comment: I think that I added metadata to the Title, AssignedTo, and Status columns. Are you saying that the above code does not do that? If so, can you provide a code example of how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use SPUser field type in this situation.

```
      newTask["AssignedTo"] = web.EnsureUser("Domain\Username");
```

Comment: As Raymond said, use SPUser type as input to AssignedTo, or send in the Users ID to the field by calling: 

    yourUser.ID

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The only tweak I had to make was escaping the backslash, so it was "Domain\\Username".

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can assing a task to SOMEBODY

```
   var somebody = new SPFieldValueCollection();
   somebody.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name));
   myTask["AssignedTo"] = somebody;
```

the status column should be ok